# How to find groups of strings in MySQL that share the same (unkown) prefixes?

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I'm hunting spammers in my forum, and noticed that frequently spammers will use email addresses from Yahoo or Gmail in the following pattern:

```
abcde*******01@gmail.com
abcde*******02@gmail.com
abcde*******03@gmail.com
```

They'll take a string of characters that are the same, followed with random gibberish. Often, but not always they'll end it with random numerals.

To find these, I'd like to pull out all user email addresses that share the same first five characters with at least two other accounts. I'm manually reviewing these before deleting, so not too worried about an infrequent false positive.

The five characters will be random, I don't know them ahead of time, just that they're shared across multiple account emails.

How can I do this in MySQL?

I'm guessing I just need to slice the first five characters off the address, then `GROUP BY` this slice having count > 2.

But I have no idea what the correct MySQL syntax for this is. I suspect it can be written without a regex, although if necessary I'm using MariaDB 10 which offers several handy regex-based SQL functions.

Comment: Just a personal opinion: I wouldn't even bother trying to do this in SQL.  Just pull the whole database into your favourite scripting language and do it there.  It's going to be slow either way, since SQL is in no way optimized for this sort of query.

Comment: See below--these queries pretty much always took less than a second no matter how I adjusted the prefix length or number of rows sharing that prefix.

Comment: Pulling the whole database into what? A text file? Would be a bad idea. There could be millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the MySQL SUBSTRING function:

```
select SUBSTRING(email,1,5),count(*) from users group by 1 having count(*)>2
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. For anyone else doing this, I found when doing that that I needed to tune the parameters a lot higher than I expected to catch mostly spammers because I had multiple legit users using emails like "abraham****@gmail.com"

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(email, 1, 5) AS prefix FROM log
GROUP BY prefix
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT email) > 2
```

I have a feeling it will be slow though. :)

EDIT: This will work in a table where multiple occurences of the same email address is a possibility, like an access log. If all emails are distinct, matthewh's solution is also okay.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, for my user's table with 30K rows, all of these queries took less than a second... no matter how I adjusted the substring length or COUNT

Comment: Those should not matter to any significant degree; the problem is in the number of rows, and the fact that grouping on a calculated field (such as `SUBSTR` result) cannot use an index; thus, each row needs to be inspected.

Comment: If you need this solution to scale up it might be a good idea to put the substring in a new column (maintained by a trigger, perhaps) and index that column.